# How to execute a column that has a multi word label?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a `csv` file that has a column named `Category Rating`. When I try to create a boxplot, I get an invalid syntax error.

```py
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11,8)})
sns.boxplot(y = inp0.Content Rating, x = inp0.Rating, palette ='Set2').set(title = "Rating versus Content Rating");
```

This is the error:

```
sns.boxplot(y = inp0.Content Rating, x = inp0.Rating, palette ='Set2').set(title = "Rating versus Content Rating");
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
```

Comment: We don't use semicolons as line end in python, you are thinking in Java. Just remove the semicolon at the end of the second line.

Comment: `inp0.Content Rating,`  You can't use a space here.
Moreover you can use semicolon but it denotes separation, rather than termination.

Comment: @EnriqueBet: I did review. New to Python. Not sure how to tackle this error.

Comment: @AchilleG, The Column name inside the CSV file is named 'Content Rating'. It's the space in between the two words that's a new issue for me. How do I write this in code?

Comment: whenever you're refering to a raw string you have to put the brackets, "Content Rating" 
I guess your line becomes `sns.boxplot(y = inp0."Content Rating", x = inp0."Rating", palette ='Set2').set(title = "Rating versus Content Rating")` but not sure whether it's the right call, i've never used sns

Comment: you can access the column as : `inp0["Content Rating"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `inp0.Content Rating` to get the attribute of `inp0`. If you have space in the column name then just use the square bracket to get the intended column as `inp0['Content Rating']`.

```
sns.boxplot(y = inp0['Content Rating'], x = inp0.Rating, palette ='Set2').set(title = "Rating versus Content Rating")
```

Answer (score 0):

first:
check if you uploaded inp0 like that :

```
inp0.Content= sns.load_dataset("data")
```

second:
try it without command .set (in the second line), you can

Comment: I uploaded as inp0 = pd.read_csv(filename.csv)